# SourceTree: undo pushed commit

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have accidentally pushed a large (complete project altering) commit to the wrong repo.

See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I have locally reverted master to the "good" commit, but I would like to revert `origin/master` to the "good" commit and prevent the "accident" commit from being pulled by others on the project.

How is the easiest/cleanest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A `git push -f origin master` (in command-line) should be enough.

With [SourceTree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294426/6309),  after selecting "`Enable Forse Push`":

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lygMh.png]

But:

> prevent the "accident" commit from being pulled by others on the project

Others might already have pulled from your project: you will have to contact them, asking them to fetch and reset their own local `master` branch to the new `origin/master`.

Comment: In the Sourcetree interface, just click Push and check the Force checkbox.

Comment: @matt True, but you must select the option "Enable force push" first in the SourceTree settings: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60294426/6309

Comment: Ok, just trying to help OP stay in Sourcetree.